# Load content every time bottom of page is reached

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to load content every time the bottom of a page is reached. (Similiar to how it works on 9GAG).
This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 300) {
  $(window).unbind('scroll');

   $.get( "content.html", function( data ) {
       $("#div").append(data);
       $(window).bind('scroll');
    });
   }   
});
```

Apparently it only works one time, altough I use **$(window).bind('scroll');**.
Is there any way I can do it, so it loads every time?

**EDIT**: The problem was that I used **>** instead of **==**, which caused the **$.get** to be fired multiple times, If I wouldn't have unbound the event. With **==** it works just fine.

Comment: Why do you unbind scroll?  That would effectively turn off your handler after it's called the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
   {

        $.get( "content.html", function( data ) {

        $("#div").append(data);

       });
   }
});
```

Here is the [blog post](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html) i made once upon a time after implementing it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unbind the scroll event.
You can create var which will be the flag if fetching data is allowed and set it before the get function to false and after the get callback back to true.

Add the flag to the if statement and this should resolve the issue.