# Do not send Ajax request until same previous Ajax request is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load "more posts" dynamicly when user scrolls down the page to the last post. - **this part is already done...**

Thing is user can of course scroll back and forth, or just scroll again and again... This would cause multiple ajax requests when not needed yet.

How do I check if the same ajax call is not already running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962117/load-content-every-time-bottom-of-page-is-reached/23962161#23962161

Comment: you can use a button instead of checking scroll position

Comment: simply when button clicked make button disable and in ajax call success enable button this will stop multiple clicks

Comment: Just use another variable? `var isLoading = false`. `function ajaxLoad() { if (isLoading) return; isLoading = true; <snip>; isLoading = false; }`

Comment: @KodleeYin I thought about that - but since these ajax calls are asynchronous - cant there be a collision?

Comment: i am understanding what are you saying

Comment: if you see my blog post i made complete tutorial

Comment: If the zero results are returned on the "final" ajax request that they should be allowed to do then set a variable e.g. loadMore = false; and check this before performing the ajax request.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you are trying to avoid the on scrolldown loading - I do NOT want to do that.

Comment: @jave.web No so long as you're blocking within the main thread of Javascript (eg. setting `isLoading = true` before the async callback). Due to Javascript's single-threaded nature, collision is never possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use something like this:

```
var loading = false;

var postLoader = function() {
    if (loading == false) {
        loading = true;

        $.ajax({

            // ajax options...

        }).always(function() {
            loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about using a global, but since these ajax calls are asynchronous - cant there be a collision?

Comment: a collision between what and what? You're just changing the value of `loading`. If `loading` is true abort any subsequent ajax calls that would have otherwise been triggered by the action of scrolling. If you for some reason need `loading` to be set across several modules, then publish it with `trigger`.

Comment: I've update the answer. Variable `loading` don't have to global for this.

Comment: a) collision of two ajax calls caused by late assigning - I am asking if some processing like "CONDITION, elsewhereCONDITION, ASSIGN, elswhere ASSIGN" can happen?
b) I think loading has to be global, since the ajax call is called on EVENT?