# PHP and jquery Ajax and infinite scroll for filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have applied the infinite-ajax-scroll to my project. It is a PHP Laravel project that displays a long list of divs. Instead of using pagination, I wanted to make the user see all results on the same page by scrolling down. I also have a filter for the results and it works well, but the strange thing is that after the results appear through filtering, scrolling down will lead to the appearance of all results without taking into account the current filter.

Can anyone advise on my best approach to this? I want to use the scrolling and it is something maybe realted to the url but I don't know how to fix this

Below is what I have so far.

//       Filters

```
    // Search functions
    function storeSearchAjax() {
        var filters = searchFilters();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            data: filters,
            url: '/restaurants/search-ajax',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function searchFilters() {
        offerFilter = $(".offerCheckbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        cuisineFilter = $(".cuisineCheckbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        freedeliveryFilter = $(".freedeliveryCheckbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        var filters = {
            "offers" : JSON.stringify(offerFilter),
            "cuisines" : JSON.stringify(cuisineFilter),
            "freedelivery" : JSON.stringify(freedeliveryFilter)
        }

        return filters;
    }

    // Paginate links
    $('#result .pagination li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var params = $.param(searchFilters());

        window.location = url+'&'+params;
    });


    $('input[name="offers[]"], input[name="cuisines[]"], input[name="freedelivery[]"]').change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        storeSearchAjax();
    });

          var page = 1;

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                    page++;
                    loadMoreData(page);
                }
            });

            function loadMoreData(page) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/restaurants/search?page=' + page,
                    type: "get",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.ajax-load').show();
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {


                    if(data.html=="") {

                        $('.ajax-load').html("");
                        return;
                    }
                    $('.ajax-load').hide();
                    $(".loading_restaurants").append(data.html);

                }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    $('.ajax-load').html("server not responding...");
                
                });
            }
```

Controller :

```
    public function ajaxSearch(Request $request)
   {

       $stores = $this->getStores($request);
  
          Helper::usePaginate();
          $stores = $stores->paginate(15)->setPath('/restaurants/search');
  
          $cuisines = Storecuisine::getStoreCuisines();
          $storedays = Storeday::getStoreDays();
          $storewhours = Storeday::all();
          $isapp_open=Helper::isAppOpen();
  
          return response()->view('store-search.stores_listing', compact('stores','storedays','isapp_open','storewhours','cuisines'));
  }
```

Comment: As I can understand you didn't add filters in your  loadMoreData function, ajax call don't have the filters in it. Its just the page number you passed.

Comment: do you have a way to solve this issue? or at least clear it to me plz

Comment: @user13908888 see in `loadMoreData(page)` you aren't passing any filtering data in "load more" functionality's api call, contrast that with `storeSearchAjax()` the initial page loader api call

Comment: @Viney please this is a question need to be solve and not to get negative comments

Comment: Fine I've deleted the offending comment

Comment: thank you can you help me please, I spent few days but didn't get how to solve it

Comment: @Viney please explain more the answer please

Comment: See in answer section. Replace your `loadMoreData()` function with that and check if it works or not

Comment: it is working fine now but if I scrolled before apply filter then the filter wont work!! and also if the results of filter is greater than pagination number then it wont scrolling to show the rest

Comment: Are you using pagination links (`#result .pagination li a`) or we can ignore that? . Regarding this _"if I scrolled before apply filter then the filter wont work!!"_ you can run `storeSearchAjax();` on page load (see updated asnwer)

Comment: I want to igonore it and use only scrolling

Comment: we are almost done, all fine just if I scrolled down before applying filters, then filter wont work!

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you mean by _"before applying filters"_ . Are there some buttons that need be clicked? . One more thing does both routes `/restaurants/search` and `/restaurants/search-ajax` map to same controller function

Comment: the issue is when I open the page for the first time, the scrolling down working fine, applying filter is working well, but if I uncheck the filter then it will not show all the result, I mean the scrolling wont work again

Comment: https://spoongate.com/ please add the location: Taman Berjaya, 43000 Kajang, Selangor, Malaysia and apply the cuisine filter only because others is not done yet and you will get the error

Comment: if I applied the filters also the problem the scrolling is not working for the filter results, it will show only 12 results

Comment: this answer is not complete, I hope you help me to fix all the issues and others can get benifit

Comment: It looks like problem is related to over jamming of network request because on my fast network it was working fine but i noticed it took a few seconds before each screen update so I opened devtools and saw in network tab there each SINGLE scroll was firing around 10-20 request instead on 1, try update 2 and let me know

Comment: so how can I solve the huge amount of requests?

Comment: Check in update you need to use debounce(aka throttle) https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/ . Let me know later, night for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadMoreData(page) {
    var filters = searchFilters();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/restaurants/search?page=' + page,
        data: filters,  // <-- this was missing
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.ajax-load').show();
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.html=="") {
            $('.ajax-load').html("");
            return;
        }
        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        $(".loading_restaurants").append(data.html);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('.ajax-load').html("server not responding...");
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    storeSearchAjax();
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

> single scroll causing 10s of request !

Actually the scroll event is firing too many times even for a "light touch"  creating many request for the same filter criteria you need to use some [deboucing](https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/) using library like lodash. So that the event fire less often and won't jam the browser or the server

Add lodash lib.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Remove this code

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
          page++;
          loadMoreData(page);
      }
  });
```

Add this instead

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        page++;
        loadMoreData(page);
    }
}, 500));
```

**UPDATE 3**

For the second issue, don't increment page on scroll rather do on the ajax success callback. And also one more thing : currently its doing ajax even if we scroll up which is wrong instead it should do ajax only when we scroll down MORE than the previous deepest point for that you need to store the deepest scroll value in some variable and use that to compare whether use has scrolled MORE deep than the previously done

```
//create on global var say 
var deepestPoint = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(function(){
    if( 
       ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() )
       &&  ($(window).scrollTop() > deepestPoint )
    ) {
        page++; //<--Remove this from here
        loadMoreData(page);
        deepestPoint = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
}, 500));

//And then


 }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.html=="") {
           $('.ajax-load').html("");
           return;
        }

        $('.ajax-load').hide();
        $(".loading_restaurants").append(data.html);
        //<--paste here
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('.ajax-load').html("server not responding...");
 });
```

Comment: updated now, it is fast but also if I uncheckd the filters, it wont back to show all results!

Comment: it will show the results but just 12 of them, the problem is the scrolling is not working

Comment: Does unchecking creates a new request? (look in network tab of devtools)

Comment: I used dd($stores) and found that if it is uncheck then it will show all the stores, which means it works but the problem is the jquery doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25040861/6160662 . We need to make sure that at time only one request should be active (means in transit). Because if you send say 20 request in parallel what wi happen when the complete ? they all will fight to append their HTML in dom which is very bad

Comment: I had a look at that question but don't know what have to do to apply in my case!

Comment: function loadMoreData(page) {
                var filters = searchFilters();
                 if (loading == false) {
                    loading = true;
               
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/restaurants/search?page=' + page,

Comment: all is fine, just the small issue, when I apply filter, the scrolling is not working and if I unchecked the filter also the scrolling is not working

Comment: if I applied filter then I applied scrolling it will work, only if I didn't use scrolling for the results before applying the filter, meaning that the scrolling will work only one time

Comment: please help me, the scrolling works only for one time

Comment: you can check online plz help

Comment: you did great job for me can you please help me in the last problem

Comment: I had to put page =1 so this will reset the pagination
    $('input[name="offers"], input[name="cuisines[]"], input[name="freedelivery"]').change(function(e) {
               page = 1;
              
            e.preventDefault();
            storeSearchAjax();
        });

Comment: Sorry just woke up, yes you need to reset the page to 1 whenever filter is applied/removed because say there are 100 food items under "Soup" cuisine. You are fetching 10 item on each scroll and user is scrolling..scrolling and currently is at say Page6 (60th item) then suppose user applied one filter for eg. "On SALE!" (but from admin panel you set only 2 soup items under SALE) then if you pass page=6(or 7 on next scroll) of course it wont show any result because you only have 2 items under SALE which can only appear on page 1

Comment: thank you, I just have 2 issues now, when aply/remove filter $('.ajax-load').show(); where the gif loading image should appear doesn't show anymore but for the first time scrolling it appears, next is when I go to inspect element-network I see if I scrolled up and down I see Rsearch?page=17.. and Rsearch?page=18.. and so on

Comment: Hi user try the update regarding 2nd issue. 1st issue looks CSS related in may be try pasting that `.ajax-load` div outside the listing container. Better you go with some [loader plugins](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/loading-indicators-jajaxloader.html)